# Updating a view in AngularJS using $watch on a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm a newbie to Angular and I'm struggling to understand how views are updated with scope changes. I am trying to update a header in my app using Angular JS based on whether a user is logged in. This information is returned by a Login service.

I have distilled my problem into two plunkers, one working and one not.

In order to get it to work I have to assign my LoginService to a variable on the scope of the HeaderCtrl.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, LoginService) {

$scope.loginService = LoginService;

$scope.$watch('loginService.isLoggedIn()', function(newVal) {
    $scope.isLoggedIn = newVal;
});
```

Here is the working version
http://plnkr.co/edit/KBzE9N?p=preview

Now if I remove the reference to the LoginService in the scope of the HeaderCtrl and just use the injected service in the watch directly, the view stops updating. That is demonstrated here
http://plnkr.co/edit/IjFS2w?p=preview

Can anyone explain to me why the second case doesn't work? I've also read that it is a bad idea to have watches inside a controller so I'm open to better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the $watch watches **scope variables** in the scope you are calling it from. In your second example, $watch is looking for a LoginService variable in your scope, which of course does not exists.